# Windows 8 Sounds

Tags: windows, audio

When I use YouTube, and go to a different tab, the sound gets turned down
(partially muted). I can manually turn the volume up, but it's very annoying
to need to do this every time I switch away from or back to the tab
where the video is playing.

How can I fix it?

I've tried disabling communication's automatic volume adjust in the sound settings but that didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to superuser are you able to provide more information such as your browser and any trouble shooting you have done to help isolate the issue?

Comment: I like thingy and thing..

Comment: Why is this on hold? the question is very clear.

Comment: @Ken I agree. More information will be needed, but the problem has been stated pretty clearly. I voted to reopen